# Adding a Favicon Via the Backend in October CMS

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend, october-form-controller

I want to create an file upload option for a favicon using the Theme Customization options:  https://octobercms.com/docs/themes/development#customization

However, if I understand correctly, favcicons (and Apple Touch Icons) need to a) have a particular name and b) be located on the root directly (i.e., www.website.com/favicon.ico).

Is it possible to use the theme customization fileupload field and have the files uploaded to the root directory and given the names required to function as favicons and apple touch icons?

If so, any idea how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For both favicon and Apple Touch icon you can declare a href attribute

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://example.com/myicon.png">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="touch-icon-iphone.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="touch-icon-ipad.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="touch-icon-iphone-retina.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="167x167" href="touch-icon-ipad-retina.png">
```

We may, alternatively, install this this free plugin: [SEO Extension](http://octobercms.com/plugin/netsti-seo)

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something, but how will the href attribute help if the icon is located in a sub-folder?  Or are you saying that the href attribute will work fine for favicons and apple touch icons even the icons are located in a sub-folder?

Answer (score 3):

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{{ 'assets/images/october.png'|theme }}">
```

Place this code in your layout file and give the full path of the favicon.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer as hardcoding the domain name in the link will lend you into nonworking urls when changing from local to production server

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do it by creating a plugin that defines a new form widget that can be used for the image upload and then for generating the required files for the favicon.